# Obtaining an acyclic graph by removing edges using an algorithm that decides ACYCLIC

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, decision-problem

i don't understand the following:

If there's an algorithm that can decide ACYCLIC in Polynomial time, then there's an algorithm who returns a set of k edges, so that the graph obtained by deleting the k edges is without cycles - in polynomial time.

The algorithm should get a directed graph and a natural k as an input, and output, if there are k edges as needed, a list of k edges, so that the graph obtained from erasing those k edges is cycles. if there are no such k edges, it simply outputs "no".

Question:my question in addition to the answer already given is this part: " then there's an algorithm who returns a set of k edges, so that the graph obtained by deleting the k edges is without cycles - in polynomial time." - what can be this algorithm? how to do it using a turing machine?

Problematic part: I can only use an algorithm that decides ACYCLIC, but it is forbidden to use any other NP-Complete algorithms, and it's running time must be polynomial in regards to its input size.

My attempt: well, to check/decide if a directed graph is ACYCLIC or not, we'll visit it topologically using DFS, then using a stack, we'll traverse edges to see if any edge in the digraph leads back to an edge already visited. if already visited - there's a cycle, if not - there's no cycle.

The algorithm: on an input of a directed graph, to check ACYCLIC:

1)finding an vertex that has only outgoing nodes - if such node doesn't exist - return "graph has cycles"

2)on that node, run DFS and traverse the digraph; add each edge found to a stack. if a vertex is shown twice - return "graph has cycles".

3)if no cycles found, accept.

But, I am not sure how to do it in regards to the algorithm required in the problem(first two paragraphs of the questions - basically, returning a set of k edges, so that by removing them, the graph will be cycles.

would really appreciate knowing how to do it.

thank you very much

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a definition of the language ACYCLIC.  Also, what is your question?  I don't see any question in your post.  What's a circle?  Do you mean cycle?  Please edit accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. edited the question. in addition to the great answer already given i was wondering - what can be the algorithm to obtain the following: "The algorithm should get a directed graph and a natural k as an input, and output, if there are k edges as needed, a list of k edges, so that the graph obtained from erasing those k edges is cycles. if there are no such k edges, it simply outputs "no"."?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** This solution assumes that the language $\text{Acyclic}$ is the language that contains exactly all acyclic directed graphs.

It is impossible to achieve this in polynomial time unless $\operatorname{P}=\operatorname{NP}$. The reason is that the problem you have to solve is NP-hard. It is called the directed feedback arc set problem. It is one of [Karp's 21 hard problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems). On the other hand, finding whether a graph is acyclic can be done with any graph traversal method in polynomial (actually linear) time. Hence, $\operatorname{P}^{\text{Acyclic}} = \operatorname P$. Hence, if you solved the task you are given in polynomial time you would have proven $\operatorname{P} = \operatorname{NP}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. my main problem is defining the following algorithm:"The algorithm should get a directed graph and a natural k as an input, and output, if there are k edges as needed, a list of k edges, so that the graph obtained from erasing those k edges is cycles. if there are no such k edges, it simply outputs "no". " - i don't know how to do it, could you help me with it please?

Comment: could you please have a look at it: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120634/obtaining-a-graph-with-no-cycles-after-removing-k-edges ?

Comment: Well if exponential running-time is okay for you, you can try removing all sets of $k$ edges and checking if the resulting graph has cycles in it. The running time in this case will be something like $O(n^k \cdot \operatorname{poly}(n))$

Comment: There are better algorithms but non of them is polynomial unless P=NP for example see this
https://engineering.tamu.edu/cse/_files/_documents/_content-documents/tamu-cs-tr-2007-7-1.pdf

Comment: I am having a problem understanding your answer, if you can, could you elaborate why if we know that it is possible to decide whether a language belongs to  ACYCLIC in polynomial time, there exists the algorithm that can return a set of k edges so that the graph after removing them contains no cycles? it would really helped me a lot if you could elaborate as much as you can

Comment: but what I said is exactly the opposite. Even if there is an algorithm for Acyclic (which does exist!), it does not help to find at set of $k$ edges in polynomial time assuming P$\neq$NP

Comment: but if according to the question there exists an algorithm that in polynomial time can decide belonging to ACYCLIC, doesn't it mean p=np? i don't understand how to use that to prove existence of the algorithm that outputs the k edges in polynomial time(i am talking only in the realm of the question)

Comment: Can you write down the definition of the acyclic language?

Comment: for a softer case, when ACYCLIC is a language that checks if a directed graph G is acyclic, is it possible to prove that?

Comment: Then as stated above it is an easy problem, it is already in P but this does not help you to solve the feedback arc set. If you find such a solution you would have proved that P=NP.