# Obtaining a graph with no cycles after removing k edges

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, computability, np-complete, dag

I am looking for an algorithm that upon an input of a directed graph G and a natural number k,outputs a set of k edges, that upon removing them, the graph will have no cycles. If there are no such k edges, it outputs "not found"

The algorithm cannot use any algorithms for NP-Complete problems - except for the one deciding if it belongs to acyclic. Its running time must be polynomial in regards to its input.

My attempt: to decide if a directed graph is acyclic, we can look for a vertex that has no incoming edges - if no such vertex to be found, it contains cycles. Upon finding such vertex, using a stack, traverse using dfs and add edges, if one vertex is found twice - than the graph contains cycles, otherwise - the graph contains no cycles.

I don't know how to design an algorithm that upon getting a directed graph G and a natural number k, outputs the set of k edges, that without them the graph will have no cycles.

It would help me a lot if you could write the algorithm in "turing machine notion"(computation/complexity) as I am trying to learn to use it properly and seeing how to do so correctly would help a lot.

Acyclic language is the language that contains all acyclic directed graphs

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: This is similar to the Feedback Vertex Set problem, that is NP-complete. I'd look if your problem is known to be NP-complete, and look for approximate algorithms (a stupid randomized algorithm would be to delete edges at random from cycles until no cycles).

Comment: sorry, it was about np complete, no np hard. i can't think of such algorithm unfortunately to satisfy the problem

Comment: I [previously suggested](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120585/obtaining-an-acyclic-graph-by-removing-edges-using-an-algorithm-that-decides-acy#comment254241_120585) that before you post this question, you should do research on the directed feedback arc set problem.  Have you done that?  If yes, can you [edit] your question to summarize what you've found so far?  If not, why not?  Doesn't Wikipedia state that the problem is NP-hard?  If so, doesn't that answer your question already?  What am I missing?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why existence of one algorithm(deciding whether a language belongs to ACYCLIC) means existence of the directed feedback arc, but i after reading and researching i am more interested for now regarding a variation of ACYCLIC to better understand it. the reason i asked this question here was because in the wikipedia page, it is written that " there exists an algorithm for solving it whose running time is a fixed polynomial in the size of the input graph (independent of the number of edges in the set) " so i was wondering - what is the algorithm?